# Solve the equation $a(x)y' + b(x)y=c(x)$. What if $a(x)=0$ somewhere? Does it always blow up?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

> Solve the equation $$a(x)y' + b(x)y=c(x)$$ (Hint: integrating factor.)

I believe that if we assume $a(x)$ is differentiable and nonzero on an interval $(\alpha, \beta)$, we can use the integrating factor $$p(x):= \exp\left[\int_\kappa^x \frac{b(\xi)-a'(\xi)}{a(\xi)} d\xi\right]\quad \text{for any }\kappa \in (\alpha, \beta)$$ and arrive at the solution $$y=\frac{\int_\kappa^x p(\eta)c(\eta)d\eta}{p(x)a(x)}+\frac{\omega}{p(x)a(x)}\quad \text{ for } \omega\in (\alpha, \beta).$$

I am wondering how to treat the case where $a(x)$ may be zero (let's assume $a(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$). I observe that we cannot expect there to be a continuous solution in general on $\mathbb{R}$ (**Edit:** or will it? $\sqrt{x}$ has unbounded derivative near zero, but does not blow up). A counterexample is if $b(x) \equiv 0$, $a(\rho)=0$, $c(\rho)\neq 0$, then the solution will blow up at $\rho$. But what if $b(\rho) \neq 0$?

Since I'm sure this is a common topic, a reading reference would be fine in lieu of an answer.

Answer (score 3):

One thing to observe is that we cannot solve a general initial value problem at a point $x_0$ with $a(x_0)=0$, as the value of $y(x_0)$ is determined by the equation. The question is whether we can have any continuous solution at all.

Not in general. Consider $$xy'+by=0\tag{1}$$ with constant $b\ne 0$. Then $(\ln y)'=y'/y = -b/x$, hence $y = Cx^{-b}$. Solutions will blow up at $0$ if $b>0$, and will be continuous if $b<0$. (For $x<0$ one should interpret $x^{-b}$ as $\pm |x|^{-b}$; the choice of sign is yours.)

Making the right-hand side nonzero won't change anything: e.g., $xy'+by=1$ reduces to the above by substitution $z=y-1$.

Such equations are usually studied when the coefficients are meromorphic functions: then one can divide by $a$ and still have meromorphic coefficients, then look for a power series solution by solving for coefficients recursively. This works better when the singular point is [regular](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_singular_point); the Wikipedia article has a few references. Of those, I looked at Chapter 4 of Teschl's book; it's quite easy to read. I recommend this book for ODE in general.

Comment: That is convenient...Teschl is the textbook for my current ODE course!

Comment: Is it really chapter 4? In my book, that chapter is called "Differential Equations in the Complex Plane".

Comment: @EricAuld Yes, and this is what my last paragraph hinted at. The main tool for handling singular points is power series. And as long as you use power series, you may as well work in the complex domain (even if you are ultimately interested only in real line). Most of Chapter 4 is about singular points: namely, everything starting with 4.2.