# Reducing Ricatti equation: $y'(x)=a(x)y(x)^2+b(x)y(x)+c(x)$...what if $a(x)=0$ somewhere?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/666497/solve-the-equation-axy-bxy-cx-what-if-ax-0-somewhere-does-it-al) I asked the other day, I am reducing the Ricatti equation $$y'(x) = a(x)y(x)^2+ b(x)y(x)+c(x)$$

to a first-order differential equation. The first step is to substitute $v(x):=y(x)a(x)$, from which we can get $$v'(x)=v(x)^2+\beta(x)v(x)+\gamma(x).$$

But what if $a(x)$ is zero somewhere? What can we do then?